# Can not find KieModule in OSGi JVM Server in CICS on ZOS

Tags: osgi, drools, cics

I am trying to set up drools on zos environment. I created my run time environment by adding the following jars (droolsjbpm-integration-distribution-6.5.0.Final) in OSGi framework bundles. I placed my drl files in unix directory outside the OSGi Application jar, when I run the OSGi app, I get the following error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule:
>   org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT   at
>   org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:186)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:180)
>     at com.cft.hogan.fwk.adapter.pem.DroolsTest.test4(DroolsTest.java:95)
>     at com.cft.hogan.fwk.adapter.pem.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:37)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)     at
>   com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.call_main(Wrapper.java:810)   at
>   com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.callOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2580)  at
>   com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.invokeJvmServerOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2455)
>     at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.jvmServerOSGiEntry(Wrapper.java:2413)
>     at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.runService(Controller.java:935)
>     at
>   com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.acceptRequest(Controller.java:230)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: I suspect this may be due to the KieModule not being visible to the classloader that is being used at the time. Following through this page: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1043888 I suggest you:
 - Add all appropriate Drools/Kie Import-Package statements as per https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/commit/d44b21b7b
 - See if that works, if not:
 - Use the KieServices.newKieClasspathContainer(ClassLoader classLoader) method and try passing in different classloaders like getClass().getClassLoader()

Comment: Using the class loader suggestion I was able to make it run using the 5.0 api a code similar to below. But I still get the same error while using the 6.0 invocation method                                                             
File path = new File("/Sample.drl"); KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = ....; kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(path),ResourceType.DRL); KnowledgeBase kbase =KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();  kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
StatefulKnowledgeSession kSession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

Comment: `KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get(); KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer(); KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules"); ` This code when runs starts giving `java.lang.IllegalStateException: There's already another KieContainer created from a different ClassLoader` in OSGi environment. I am using drools 6.5.

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
    getClass().getClassLoader()); KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get(); KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer(); KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules"); ` This code when runs starts giving `java.lang.IllegalStateException: There's already another KieContainer created from a different ClassLoader` in OSGi environment. I am using drools 6.5.